# Why is this SVG animation not working

Tags: animation, path, svg, smil

I have a L-shaped `<path>` element and I try to `<animate>` its `d` attribute to make it grow  smoothly: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Mathiasa/be5HS

I tried it before with an S-shape and it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mathiasa/bq9dt/

Why does the L-shape not zoom like the S-shape - As I use the same method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paths must contain the same segment types in order to have non-discrete animation. Your to path ends with L, L, z path segments at the end whereas the other paths end as V, L, z

I've corrected your example so that all paths end L, V, z: http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/4UaQj/